# Visual Studio Exstensibility How to Create Cutom Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsx, vspackage

I'm attempting to use Visual Studio extensibility (VSX) to create a visual studio custom designer.  I'm using the default extensibility 'Package' project type with the Visual Studio package creation wizard which provides for the creation of a custom editor.  This is great!  However, I want to create my own custom designer and the wizard only creates a customer editor but not a custom designer.

Does anyone have an example or *any* reference documentation on how to create a custom designer even if just modifying the VS wizard created customer editor?

So far I've used the Visual Studio package project wizard to create a customer editor.  Commencing from the default code created by the Custom Editor Wizard I have changed the following:
**1)** Updated the Window Pane from the Editor's Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane type to the Designer's Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.DesignerWindowPane.  I've implemented the interfaces on the DesignerWindowPane.
I updated the EditorFactory to reflect the change in Window Pane type.
**2)** Then I added the following attributes to the package class.

```
[DesignSurfaceExtensionAttribute(typeof(TierDesigner))]
[ProvideObjectAttribute(typeof(TierDesigner))]
[ProvideServiceAttribute(typeof(TierDesigner))]
```

I also modified the logical view attribute to

```
    [ProvideEditorLogicalView(typeof(EditorFactory), VSConstants.LOGVIEWID.Designer_string)]
```

Although I haven't removed any of the default editor attributes

```
    [ProvideEditorExtension(typeof(EditorFactory), ".ld", 50, 
          ProjectGuid = Guids.PckgGuid, 
          TemplateDir = "Templates", 
          NameResourceID = 105,
          DefaultName = "Layers")]
```

**3)** I've added a DesignSurfaceExtension type of class TierDesigner as reflected in the attributes in 2 above.

Testing via the experimental hive I create the custom file type '.ld' through the VS file menu and add to a csproj.  When I click on the '.ld' file to open the EditorFactory runs fine, it creates the WindowsDesignerPane type and once it exits from the EditorFactory code it crashes with error code **'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0:8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).**

I'm believe there is something I haven't implemented but haven't been able to find the exact issue.

So far I've used Dive Deep VSX series [VSX Information](https://learnvsxnow.codeplex.com/) and the Visual Studio 2010 SDK code samples but neither of these provides any reference on creating custom designers and I haven't been able to find reference documentation anywhere at all.

I'm attempting to use a customer designer to automate some boilerplate tier code based on tiers created in the custom designer.

Any help, examples or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the happy world of Visual Studio extensibility :-). What I suggest is 1) configure 1st chance exceptions in Visual Studio ("debug"/"exceptions"/"thrown") and 2) debug your project in the EXP hive, so you should be able to spot the root cause of E_UNEXPECTED.